# Transform levels to dataframe column in r

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and i am troubled with transforming dataframe.

so i have

```
**user**    **category**    **Frequency**
John        Sports            2
John        Finance           3
Dave        Health            1
Kirby       Sports            1
Kirby       Health            4
```

but i want it to be

```
**user**    **Sports**    **Finance**    **Health**
John          2             3              0
Dave          0             0              1
Kirby         1             0              4
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Try `data.table::dcast(x,user~category,fill=0)` (you need the `data.table` package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some `tidyr` in your life:

```
df_long <-
  tibble::tribble(~user,    ~category, ~Frequency,
                 'John',   'Sports',          2,
                 'John',  'Finance',          3,
                 'Dave',   'Health',          1,
                'Kirby',   'Sports',          1,
                'Kirby',   'Health',          4)

df_wide <- tidyr::spread(data = df_long, key = category, value = Frequency, fill = 0)
```

So the Key is the column that becomes the new column names, and the value is the column that fills in the values below them. `tidyr::gather` does the opposite.

Comment: thanks that works! you just help me from having nightmare tonight